# CopyFromRecordset from Access to Excel is out of Order

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Very frustrating results from:

```
ws.Range(myExcelTable).CopyFromRecordset rs
' myExcelTable is a named table with assigned range
```

The pull for rs (the recordset, is a select all, doesn't matter if it is done this way or with field names, it is the same result)

```
cmdSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM " & myAccessTable
rs.Open cmdSQL2, conn
```

For an unknown reason it copies records into excel in this order (using pID to show ordering):

3-8

0-2

9-number of records

I have tried several range methods and the result is the same.
I will "hand bomb" them here to cut out the extra work I performed in building range strings.

```
ws.Range("S4").CopyFromRecordset rs

ws.Range("S4:BP258").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

This behavior does not appear if the table you are copying from Access has only one Field (column) and the Table in Excel has a single header (column), but it is appearing for me now in this multi-field table.

I feel this is happening when the recordset is actually created somehow and not on the "paste" or assignment side (Excel).

[image]

'*************************************************************************

Problem Solved by this SO Contributor (will leave here until it is placed as an answer):
https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-a

Using ORDER BY in the sql sommand:

```
cmdSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM " & myAccessTable & " ORDER BY " & primaryKey
```

From immediate window (removes the variables so you can see the command better for those new to such things:

**SELECT * FROM County_Directory ORDER BY [pID]**

'*************************************************************************

Comment: I don't see an `ORDER BY` there, so the ordering is undefined (any order is valid). Recordsets tend to be ordered by the primary key, but they don't need to be. If you want a specific order, add an `ORDER BY` clause to the SQL statement.

Comment: @erik-a I feel very stupid, Sorting the Access Tables and depending on the Primary Key [pID].  Thank you!  Put it down as the answer please and I will accept it.  cmdSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM " & myAccessTable & " ORDER BY " & primaryKey